# How to remove the action parameter from HTTP Content-type of SOAP request?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a 3rd party web service, here is a part of it's WSDL:

```
<wsdl:operation name="PerformOperation">
  <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
  <wsdl:input name="PerformOperationRequest">
    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="PerformOperationResponse">
    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Notice that soapAction is empty, but for some reason the service can't process requests which Content-type contains action="", 3rd party support says that requests shouldn't contain action parameter at all to be processed.

I've used JAX-WS to generate necessary objects by the WSDL and now my requests have the next Content-type in the HTTP header:

```
Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset="utf-8";action=""
```

I wonder how to get rid of the empty action parameter in the Content-type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

First I tried to use a local copy of the WSDL file without this annoying action description line: `<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>` It doesn't help, `action=""` was still present in the Content-Type.
But then I remembered about the `SOAPHandler` interface.

I wrote something like this:

```
class RemoveActionHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        if ("".equals(context.get(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY)))
            context.put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, null);

        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```

and then used it this way:

```
((BindingProvider)soapServicePort).getBinding()
     .setHandlerChain(Collections.<Handler>singletonList(new RemoveActionHandler()));
```